# Rails Active Record Name Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm facing the following error:

```
NameError at 
uninitialized constant XController::Sheep
```

at this line

```
server = Sheep.find_by_id(id)
```

This is my setup:

Under `models/sheep.rb`

```
class Sheep < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end
```

Under `models/kid.rb`

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sheep # I tried adding , :class_name => 'Sheep' didn't do anything
end
```

Under `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
    inflect.uncountable 'sheep'
end
```

The table name is actually `sheep` I checked

What else should I check?

EDIT:
In the controller `controllers/farm.rb` I make two calls:

```
@kid = Kid.find_by_id params[:id]
@sheep = Sheep.find_by_id(id) # works only when adding :: as in the answer
```

Comment: In what file are you calling `Sheep.find_by_id(id)` ? Can you try using `::Sheep.find_by_id(id)` instead?

Comment: it worked! but how come I can reference other models with just        Kid.find_by_name params[:name] without needing the ::? (same controller too)

Comment: I don't know, you didn't answer the first question so I can't help you...

Comment: A controller I said? under controllers.

Comment: I need the name of the file + the full name of the controller (the declaration that should look like `class SheepController < ApplicationController`) Also, are you using any gem for Controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try accessing this model's name with double colon:

```
server = Sheep.find_by_id(id)
# become
server = ::Sheep.find_by_id(id)
         ^^
```

Then it should work.

I don't have enough infos yet to tell why it is not working without the colons, but my intuition tells me that `XController::Sheep` suggests you have a problem in you Controller's names.

Comment: The controller name is farm, nothing special